# Responsive website not working in Firefox

Tags: html, css

I am building a carousel which works fine. Only thing is i can not make this 100% responsive, it seems to be working in webkit browsers but not in firefox. The images resize nicely but the li width stay the same size of the original image therefore i get large gaps in between my images?

```
.carousel{
    height:100%;
}
.carousel ul { 
    overflow:hidden; 
    white-space:nowrap; 
    margin:0; padding:0; 
    list-style:none; 
    position:relative; 
    height:100%; 
    background:#99F; 
}
.carousel li { 
    display:inline-block; 
    background:#FFC; 
    height:100%;
}
.carousel li img{
    height:100%;
}

<div class="carousel">

   <ul>
       <li><img src="car"  /></li>
       <li><img src="boat"  /></li>
       <li><img src="train"  /></li>
       <li><img src="car"  /></li>
       <li><img src="boat"  /></li>
       <li><img src="train"  /></li>
   </ul>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this code the it should work.
`min-height` works on FF

```
html,body {
min-height:100%;
height:100%;   
}
```

Comment: Nah still not working, The height resizes ok. My image width resizes but my li width doesn't. So i get left with a gap in between the two?